# Cant pg_restore on Heroku: "could not read from input file: end of file"

Tags: postgresql, heroku, heroku-postgres

I am trying to copy my local PostgreSQL DB to Heroku app with `pg_dump` / `pg_restore` utils. Doing according to Heroku's official guide: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgres-import-export

So, i've done the dump:
`pg_dump -Fc --no-acl --no-owner -h localhost -U myuser mydb > mydb.dump`

Then i've uploaded it on a reachable across the web server (and its really reachable, i've checked it downloading the file with `wget` and `pg_restore`ing it - works fine).

Then i've tried to restore in on Heroku and no luck:

```
kulver@kvb:~/projects/gop/gop_flask$ heroku pg:backups restore 'MY_URL_HERE' postgresql-corrugated-15763
r010 ---restore---> DATABASE
An error occurred and your backup did not finish.

Please run `heroku pg:backups info r010` for details.
```

Here are the details:

```
kulver@kvb:~/projects/gop/gop_flask$ heroku pg:backups info r010
=== Backup info: r010

Database:    BACKUP
Started:     2016-03-26 20:15:32 +0000
Finished:    2016-03-26 20:15:32 +0000
Status:      Failed
Type:        Manual
Backup Size: 23.9MB
=== Backup Logs
... a bunch of logs here ...
2016-03-26 20:15:32 +0000: pg_restore: processing data for table "cards"
2016-03-26 20:15:32 +0000: waiting for restore to complete
2016-03-26 20:15:32 +0000: pg_restore: [custom archiver] could not read from input file: end of file
2016-03-26 20:15:32 +0000: restore done
2016-03-26 20:15:32 +0000: waiting for download to complete
2016-03-26 20:15:32 +0000: download done
```

I've tried to remake the dump file, reload it - same error. What's wrong? Why can i download it and restore from it on the just created DB, but not on Heroku?

Thank you for any advise.

Comment: This solution may be relevant to some people: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42433414/heroku-database-restore-issue/42435490#42435490

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I failed to load the dump in the exact described above way, BUT i've come to another solution which worked fine for me:

Make the dump in simple SQL format:
`pg_dump --no-owner mydb > mydb.dump`

You may need to switch to the user who has rights to access your DB, `postgres` for example. So, `sudo su postgres` and then make the dump.

And then load it with `psql` tool:
`user@pc:~/path/to/your/dump$ heroku pg:psql < mydb.dump`

Comment: Thanks Mikhail. Had the same problem. This process is much easier and worked for me.

Answer (score 5):

There appears to be an issue with piping to the file. I created the dump using the -f command to specify the file and that solved my issue.

```sh
pg_dump -f mydb.dump -Fc --no-acl -no-owner -h localhost -U myUser --schema=public myDatabase
```

Answer (score 1):

Just experienced this problem, I wasn't able to get it to work with the answers provided here, but changing the extension of the output file to `.psql` managed to fix it for some reason

```sh
pg_dump -Fc --no-acl --no-owner -h localhost -U myuser mydb > mydb.psql
```