# Heroku: pg_restore: [archiver] unsupported version (1.14) in file header

Tags: heroku, heroku-postgres

I have a local Postgresql database that I am trying to import into a Heroku instance. I have Postgresql 12.1 installed. To create the dump file I am running:

`pg_dump -Fc --no-acl --no-owner -h localhost -U nico nicoportfolio_development > mydb.dump`

I then add the dump file to an aws s3 bucket.

Following the heroku documentation, I then create a presigned url:

`aws s3 presign s3://nicoportfolio/mydb.dump`

Finally I run the `heroku pg restore` command

`heroku pg:backups:restore 'https://nicoportfolio.s3.amazonaws.com/mydb.dump?AWSAccessKeyId=AKIA2LPDMAPORY7QOOUK&Expires=1577325774&Signature=z6mBKKOVd6wPcFtCc8cjkjoKTLA%3D' DATABASE_URL`

I get the following error:

`pg_restore: [archiver] unsupported version (1.14) in file header`

I've read several other posts regarding this topic which mentioned an outdated version of Postgres causing the problem but I have the most up to date version.

Comment: Found a solution to my question on this SO post: [https://stackoverflow.com/a/36248298/5656846](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36248298/5656846)

Answer (score 3):

Saving you a click, here's the fix:

Make the dump in simple SQL format:

```
pg_dump --no-owner mydb > mydb.dump
```

You may need to switch to the user who has rights to access your DB, postgres for example. So,

```
sudo su postgres
```

and then make the dump.

And then load it with psql tool:

```
user@pc:~/path/to/your/dump$ heroku pg:psql < mydb.dump
```

Answer (score 0):

My issue here was that my version of postgres on Heroku was old (10.x).  You can check this by going to the postgres add-on page for your app.

This has pretty clear instructions to upgrade: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/upgrading-heroku-postgres-databases