# pg_restore: [custom archiver] could not read from input file: end of file

Tags: docker-compose, postgresql-9.6, pg-dump, pg-restore

I have a dump of my production db, which I can restore easily in my docker container with: `docker exec -it my_db_container pg_restore --user=my_user --dbname=dbname sql/current.dump`. Everything works, data are here.

But when I re-dump my local database from the docker with `docker exec -it my_db_container -U my-user -F c -b dbname > docker/db/current_stripped.dump` back to project folder, my dump file is created (with appropriate size and content) but I can not use it for restoring (`docker exec -it whasq-db pg_restore --user=my-user --dbname=dbname sql/current_stripped.dump`) it again to a fresh db due to an error: `pg_restore: [custom archiver] could not read from input file: end of file` however the restore command is the same (except the `my_user` which is postgres in production) as used in production env.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and solved it as follows. I switched to the `-f` or `--file` option instead of piping (taken from https://stackoverflow.com/a/51073680/6593069). And I created the dump file inside the container and then copied it to my host.

That would mean in your case:

```
docker exec -it my_db_container -U my-user -F c -b dbname -f current_stripped.dump
docker cp my_db_container:current_stripped.dump .
```